# Replacement for Netmeeting

Tags: remote, presentations

We've been using Netmeeting for doing presentations with remote workers. Now that MS has disowned it (and it doesn't run on Vista - mostly), we need something else. Since Netmeeting was free, our budget is right around $0. We don't need audio or video, but do need to share apps/desktop and allow a remote user to take control.

What are some good cheap/free alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

[Yugma](https://www.yugma.com/) is a free alternative that I've used before.

With priced options there is

- [WebEx](http://webex.com/)
- [GoToMeeting](https://www1.gotomeeting.com/?Portal=gotomeeting.com)
- [Yugma Pro](https://www.yugma.com/products/product_tour.php)

Comment: WebEx works great - crazy expensive though.

Comment: I agree, that's why I've been leaning more towards Yugma as of late

Comment: GoToMeeting works well for us, we stopped using WebEx due to price.

Answer (score 5):

[Office Communications Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicationsserver/default.aspx) might not be that expensive. If your company has licensed the [Enterprise](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites/FX101674041033.aspx) version of Office, it already comes with a Client Access License for Communicator.

That makes the price of OCS only $700 (for the server), even if you have thousands of clients.

Food for thought.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Microsoft SharedView](http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=94) It works great in VISTA and it's very easy to use.

Comment: Tried using this on XP and got no where. And then it crashed.

Comment: Shog9, my experience is different. I have used it many times on XP  without problems.

Comment: I'm sure lots of folks have. But for those of us with the wrong video hardware / drivers / multiple monitors / ??? ... it's effectively useless. And cleaning up that last 10% of breakage doesn't exactly appear to be much of a priority for the developers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend Citrix's [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com). I have used it to do both presentations and remote support. Its very simple to use and has worked very well for me in the past, even over poor internet connections.

Comment: I've used it, but $50/month is a little pricey.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/).  The free version has some OS limitations, but works well.  May not work for you b/c you have to pay for the Vista and Mac versions.

Comment: I second this suggestion. VNC has worked very well for my distributed team. The supported version of VNC have some nice features that are worth paying for.

Answer (score 1):

We've used both LiveMeeting and Webex with good results.

Answer (score 1):

I use SharedView when doing over the web training. It allows the other user to highlight and point to things with their own mouse so you can see what they are talking about.

It's free and has worked very well. The only downside is that all participants must have a Live account (free) in order to start or join sessions.

Answer (score 1):

DimDim is free (for small meetings that don't need branding) and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

i've used radmin for this purpose. it allows file transfer, etc. iirc costs about $50 
http://www.radmin.com

Answer (score 0):

adobe's [connect now](http://acrobat.com/) looks slick.

Comment: URL: http://www.adobe.com/acom/connectnow/

Comment: Connectnow works well, but my experience is that it's really, really slow on older machines (it was a slideshow on an old Pentium 4-based Celeron 2.0 Ghz CPU).  Also, it's $40 per month if you want to have meetings with more than 5 people.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Vyew](http://www.vyew.com) for the last year or so. It's cross platform so Windows, Mac and Linux users can both view and share their screens.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [ConferenceXP](http://cct.cs.washington.edu/).

> ConferenceXP is a shared-source
>   research platform developed by
>   Microsoft Research that provides
>   simple, flexible, and extensible
>   conferencing and collaboration using
>   high-bandwidth networks and the
>   advanced multimedia capabilities of
>   Microsoft Windows. ConferenceXP helps
>   researchers and educators develop
>   innovative applications and solutions
>   that feature broadcast-quality audio
>   and video in support of real-time
>   distributed collaboration and distance
>   learning environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a quick replacement, you could use the Vista-integrated "Windows Collaboration".  It's gotten some bad reviews though, I'd check to make sure it meets your needs first.