# How to share the Windows Desktop with several other users over Internet?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, presentations

I'm looking for tool where I can share my desktop and the programs I'm running with other users over Internet to be able to run demonstrations. Something like Remote Desktop or VNC but with more than one user seeing my desktop.

Answer (score 7):

You could use some web conferencing software such as [Go To Meeting](https://www2.gotomeeting.com/) or [WebEx](http://www.webex.co.uk/).

Comment: I use WebEx frequently.  I've only used it with windows clients, but it "just works."

Answer (score 3):

**vnc** can handle multiple users, and is fairly simple.

I've heard good things about **gotomeeting**

A free option for web conferencing is **dimdim**

Answer (score 1):

There are some suggestions here: [Replacement for Netmeeting](https://serverfault.com/questions/1383/replacement-for-netmeeting)

Answer (score 1):

TightVNC with the `DFMirage mirror display driver` is pretty nice I've just used it with 2 connected users as a time but it has worked well, as far as I know the only limiting factor would be your bandwidth. I use it a lot on my network to control POS computers through VPN.

There also exists an application from the guys at TightVNC called [TightProjector](http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/), I havn't used it myself and it sadly isn't a free program but it might be useful. :)

Comment: TightVNC and the DFMirage mirror display driver can be downloaded from http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to a few episodes of SecurityNow and you can't fail to learn about [GoToMeeting](https://www2.gotomeeting.com/entry/entry.tmpl?Action=rgoto&_sf=1) from Citrix.

Comment: SecurityNow can be found at http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Technically at least in regard to Windows XP, `termserv.dll` can be patched to allow [concurrent Remote Desktop sessions](http://alonbilu.wordpress.com/2008/05/17/enabling-multiple-concurrent-remote-sessions-on-windows-xp-sp3-patched-file-included/) (I'm not sure how that's received). I've experimented and it's really not all that disagreeable. It's been some time since then however, and I never tried more than two users.

Answer (score 0):

This one is no frills and free...
https://www.yugma.com/

Answer (score 0):

Gotomeeting is perfect for this.  It can be set to share a whole desktop, or share individual windows.  It can record your demo sessions for later presentations (including voice).

You can also change presenters mid-way through, and give control of your applications to other users.

It also works perfectly (as user and presenter) through https proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vista by chance, you already have the tool.  Windows Meeting Space comes with every version of Vista except home basic.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/meeting-space.aspx