# Desktop sharing for training and online meetings - internal LAN use only

Tags: windows, desktop, screen-sharing

What is a nice way to enable desktop sharing for a bunch of users connected to terminal servers? Something like VNC display host on many clients, but the users will generally be connected to the one terminal server with the same IP address. The situation will most likely be for sharing desktops for training or meeting purposes. Is way to leverage the inbuilt 'remote control' of terminal server sessions, or can you recommend a web service that will do this nicely, and play nicely with Term Server sessions.

All the users (for now) are connected by VPN to central terminal servers. Does Net Meeting ring a bell?

The terminal server(s) is W2k3, which is not supported by Netmeeting or Meeting Space

I am ideally looking for something like Netmeeting (supported upto W2k) and Windows Meeting Space (supported in Vista) http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/meeting-space.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [ConferenceXP](http://cct.cs.washington.edu/).

> ConferenceXP is a shared-source
>   research platform developed by
>   Microsoft Research that provides
>   simple, flexible, and extensible
>   conferencing and collaboration using
>   high-bandwidth networks and the
>   advanced multimedia capabilities of
>   Microsoft Windows. ConferenceXP helps
>   researchers and educators develop
>   innovative applications and solutions
>   that feature broadcast-quality audio
>   and video in support of real-time
>   distributed collaboration and distance
>   learning environments.

Answer (score 1):

WebEx works fine too on Terminal Servers.  I'm not sure how it will work on many TS sessions inside a Terminal Server (single session usage is about 40MB RAM/Java-based), you can try this by launching a Demo: [www.webex.com](http://www.webex.com)

There are other posts about these kinds of products:
[**https://serverfault.com/questions/1383/replacement-for-netmeeting**](https://serverfault.com/questions/1383/replacement-for-netmeeting)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [LiveMeeting](http://livemeeting.com)? I know Microsoft uses this for a lot of their webcasts they do.